# Drop Down Navigation Menu That Shows Latest Post per Category

Tags: php, wordpress, navigationbar

So I'm trying to work on my navigation menu in my wordpress website. I'm trying to copy the navigation menu from hongkiat.com (shown in the image).

In Hongkiat's navigation menu, you'll see the FIVE (5) Parent Categories (Design /dev, Technology, Inspiration, SOcial COmmerce and Deal). Once the user hovered on a Parent Category, it will show the recent posts under the Parent Category.

Anyway, I managed to code the Drop down menu with the Parent Category showing plus it's child category. Now the dilemma lies on how can I display the latest post *(at least 3 posts)* under the parent category that is hovered by the user.

[image]

Anyway, here's my code:

**HTML/PHP**

```
<ul>
    <?php 

        global $post;
        $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=3&offset=1');
        foreach($myposts as $post) ;


        $args = array(
        'show_option_all'    => '',
        'hide_empty'         => '0',
        'orderby'            => 'name',
        'order'              => 'ASC',
        'style'              => 'list',
        'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
        'child_of'           => 0,
        'hierarchical'       => 1,
        'title_li'           => (''),
        'show_option_none'   => __( '' ),
        'number'             => null,
        'echo'               => 1,
        'depth'              => 2,
        'current_category'   => 0,
        'pad_counts'         => 0,
        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
        'walker'             => null
        );
        wp_list_categories( $args ); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.navone {
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family: "Raleway",san-serif;
    font-feature-settings: normal;
    font-kerning: auto;
    font-language-override: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-synthesis: weight style;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.navone ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.navone ul ul {
    display: none;

}

.navone ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.navone ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}

.navone ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

.navone ul li {
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px 20px;
}

.navone ul li:hover {
    background:#000;
}

.navone ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
    
.navone ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navone ul li ul {
    width:200px;
    z-index:9;
}

.navone ul ul {
    background: #000;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
}

.navone ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
    padding:5px 10px;
}

.navone ul ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navone ul ul li a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.navone ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}

.navone ul li ul li {
    padding:8px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}
.navone ul li ul li:hover {
    border-left:5px solid #F52100;
    padding-left:20px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.navtwo {
    display:inline;
}
```

IF anyone could help me or point out what i'm missing because my code doesn't work. My code doesn't have errors but Im not achieving what I want to accomplish.

Could anyone extend their helping hand.

Comment: IMO, the best place to get a solid answer for this would be [wordpress.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), although you will likely get some fantastic answers here no doubt, it's more specialised over there :P

Comment: thank you sam, I just thought that this is a PHP related question. people can help out.

Comment: The easiest way I'd do it is to first: create a megamenu (extended menu), and then add in my menu walker way to add sidebars. Then you can register sidebars and populate it with any widget you wish (including your own). I have made a [menu walker gist](https://gist.github.com/dingo-d/73488da35e6a77e6cd1c) that you can check out, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php $args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'child_of'                 => 0,
        'parent'                   => '',
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'exclude'                  => '',
        'include'                  => '',
        'number'                   => '',
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => false

);

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach($categories as $cat)
{ 
    if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {

?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $cat->name; $cat_id = $cat->term_id;?>
        <?php $post_args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'cat' => $cat_id
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
        if($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </li>
<?php } }?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Ash Patel,  Thank you for your answer. For some weird reasons.. The Child Category shows up. YOu may see my testing website here:

http://alphaomega.bendaggers.com/ What I'm trying to achieve is It only shows the Parent at the Menu. Then when it was hovered, the first 3 post published in the parent category shows up. Child Category should not be displayed as a sub menu. and btw, I have edited a little in your code to add the post thumbnail. CSS is a little messed up. Could you help on this?

Comment: FYI. I only have 5 Parent categories. and more than 15 child category.

Comment: I have edited above answer ..please check it once..:)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
<ul>
<?php $args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'child_of'                 => 0,
        'parent'                   => '',
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'exclude'                  => '',
        'include'                  => '',
        'number'                   => '',
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => false

);

$categories = get_categories( $args );

foreach($categories as $cat): ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $cat->$name; $cat_id = $cat->$term_id;?>
        <?php $post_args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'cat' => $cat_id
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
        if($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It's not tested but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have been missing few things in the above code .

Let's try to make it simple.

**Step 1** : Get all the parent categories and child categories under them inside an array named as `$total_categories`

You can see the code below to get the array for all parent categories and child categories

```
<?php 
$parent_args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'parent'                   => '0',
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 0,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => false
);
$parent_categories = get_categories( $parent_args );

foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
    $child_args = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'parent'                   => $parent_category->term_id,
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 0,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => false
    );  
    $cats_arr = array(); 
    $child_categories = get_categories( $child_args ); 
    $cats_arr[] = $parent_category->term_id;
    foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
        $cats_arr[] = $child_category->term_id;
    }

    $total_categories[$parent_category->term_id] = $cats_arr;
}
?>
```

> Output Provided was for my case

Above array will look as  where **18** is the parent category ID and the child categories are **19 and 20** plus we have also included the parent category ID **(18)** in the array as well as index of the array.

```
Array
(
    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 19
            [2] => 20
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

)
```

Now simply traverse the array `$total_categories` to get all the parent categories and **top 3 posts** under that categories

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($total_categories as $total_category_k=>$total_category_v): ?>
        <li>

            <a href=""><?php echo get_the_category_by_ID($total_category_k);?></a>
        <?php $post_args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'orderby'=>'ID',
            'order'=>'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => $total_category_v,
                                    'operator' => 'IN'
                                ),
                            ),
            );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
        if($the_query->have_posts()): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

> Output Provided was for my case
>
> And it will finally give you the desired HTML with required content output as below :

```
<ul>
        <li>

            <a href="">menu</a>
            </li>
        <li>

            <a href="">test</a>
            </li>
        <li>

            <a href="">Uncategorized</a>
                <ul>
                                <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/clark_atlanta_university/students-unlock-the-mysteries-of-the-brain-with-nih-scientists/">Students unlock the mysteries of the brain with NIH scientists</a>
                    </li>
                                <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/clark_atlanta_university/contacts-better-than-permanent-lenses-for-babies-after-cataract-surgery/">Contacts better than permanent lenses for babies after cataract surgery</a>
                    </li>
                                <li>
                        <a href="http://localhost/wp/clark_atlanta_university/nih-announces-recruitment-for-clinical-trial-to-test-new-tinnitus-treatment-device/">NIH announces recruitment for clinical trial to test new tinnitus treatment device</a>
                    </li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

The code you were missing was :

```
'orderby'=>'ID',
'order'=>'DESC',
```

> To get the top 3 posts you will have to get the posts in descending
>   order by ID and of course posts_per_page will get you 3 records only

```
'tax_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'    => $total_category_v,
                                        'operator' => 'IN'
                                    ),
                                ),
                );
```

> And to get posts related to categories (whether the parent or child )
>   so we have passed the array containing the parent as well as child
>   categories

Comment: and sorry I am not a design guy , but you can create a design of the dropdown .. I hope your original one will also work